# New kernel using secure boot is it possible?

Tags: boot, kernel

I would know if it possible to use a new kernel using secure Boot. I downloaded the kernel 5.8 but it works just if I disable the secure boot(if I use secure boot, it doesn't let me use it ). Moreover, once time, I was updating something on the terminal and It asked me to use a kernel singed (or something like that ). I had to remove the new kernel then to use the old kernel and update. I'm a new user and I was wondering if someone can help me. I have to use a nw kernel because I have some problem with the old kernel like using wi-fi and to regulate the brightness( I am using ryzen4500).

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign the kernel.
the following [tutorial] (https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot) provides both the background and method for you.

Briefly :
create keys to sign your kernel/modules.

enrol keys onto your computer in BIOS.

use keys to sign.

as keys match between bios secure boot and the kernel you can run in secure boot.

I have done this for some development serial drivers I use on my server